# How to achieve toggle effect with jQuery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found one example that is exactly what I would like to have.
Please resize your window to 700px less and url is http://www.subway.com.au

thanks for reading this.

My layout is as the following:

```
<div id="left">
  <div id="left-container" style="display:none;">Content foo
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div id="right-container" style="display:none;">Content bar
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Basically, when click either #left or #right, relatively the #left-container or #right-container will slideUp or slideDown, and at the same time .overlay will be showed or hidden. Of course, when containers are slideUp, clicking all screen rather than itself will slideDown and removeClass .overlay.

I know this question has been brought over a lot of times. However it seems still not working for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you show us your JavaScript?

Comment: "Of course, when containers are slideUp, clicking all screen rather than itself will slideDown and removeClass .overlay." Can you precise that sentence as well please?

Comment: Found a good example. http://www.subway.com.au please resize screen smaller than 700px; Mine JS is a total mess. won't help any.

Comment: can you setup a fiddle with css/js codes included?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a little different HTML for that -

```
<div id="left" class="header">
    A
  <div class="container">Content foo
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right" class="header">
    B
  <div class="container">Content bar
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

and with the JS -

```
$(function(){
    $(".header").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).find(".container").is(":visible")){
            $(".header").find(".container").each(function(){
                 $(this).slideDown();
            });
            $(this).find(".container").slideUp();
            $(".overlay").show();
        }else{            
            $(this).find(".container").slideDown();
            $(".overlay").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n8ykqLuy/1/

**NOTE:** At first I thought your requirement was custom. But I think what you are looking for is an accordion.

Comment: That is so close. However, if A container has slideUp, and when B is clicked, A container would need to slideDown, and then B container will slideUp?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Would you please check http://www.subway.com.au and resize the window to less than 700px. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve.